# Check to see if a single object exists in an s3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

As far as I can tell from the docs, my options are either (a) list *all* of the object (via `listObjects()`), or just try to grab the object (via `getObject()`). The downside of `getObject` is that, while it will let me know if the object doesn't exist (by means of a 404), if it *does* exist. It downloads, and all I want to know is whether or not its there so I can update the user's display.

I could use `listObjects` and then filter on my end.. but.. surely there's a method available, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `headObject()`.  This just returns metadata on the object.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property